# Rails ActiveRecord: Where to define method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a question about ActiveRecord of Rails.

For example I have a `Service` model, and `Service` has `name` as a column.

This is `app/model/service.rb`

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.class_method
    puts 'This is class method'
  end

  def instance_method
    puts 'This is instance method'
  end
end
```

Then I can do,

```
Service.class_method #=> 'This is class method'

Service.find(1).instance_method #=> 'This is instance method'
```

This is easy. But when I get ActiveRecord Instance in Array, for example

```
Service.where(id: [1,2,3])
```

and I need method like,

```
Service.where(id: [1,2,3]).sample_method

def sample_method
  self.length
end
```

but how and where to define method for Active Record Array? I want to handle this object just like other `Service` class or instances.

Thanks.

Comment: Update the first paragraph too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `where` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object, not an array. It behaves similar to an array, but inherits a load more methods to process data/ construct SQL for querying a database.

If you want to add additional functionality to the ActiveRecord::Relation class, you can do something like this:

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation 
  def your_method
    # do something
  end
end
```

This will need to reside somewhere meaningful, such as the lib directory or config/initializers.

This should allow you to do something like

```
Service.where(id: [1,2,3]).your_method
```

You can do something similar for any Ruby class, like the Hash, or Array class as well.

However, there's almost ALWAYS a better solution than extending/ overriding Rails/ Ruby source classes...

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. yes, `where` returns ActiveRecord::Relation object, not an array. So the best way is to inherit ActiveRecord::Relation class and add instance method. Thanks.

Comment: You can do that yes- but generally speaking, adding methods to the ActiveRecord::Relation class isn't the best way. I personally would create a separate class or module and pass the result of Service.where(id: [1,2,3]) to it. You can then do what you need to do in that class, without changing the behavior of ActiveRecord::Relation. This is better practice, as your specific functionality can be tested in isolation, and doesn't risk changing the stock behavior of the Relation class in other areas of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods like `get_count` and `get_name` are a bit pointless... Why not just do:

```
Service.count

Service.find(1).name
```

Class methods like `count`, and instance methods like `name` (i.e. database column names) are all *public* - so you don't need to define your own getter methods.

As for your second example, you *could* just write the following:

```
Service.where(id: [1,2,3]).map{ |s| s.name }
```

Or equivalently:

```
Service.where(id: [1,2,3]).map(&:name)
```

But the following is actually more efficient, since it is performing the calculation *in SQL* rather than in ruby. (If you're confused what I mean by that, try running both versions and compare what SQL is generated, in the log):

```
Service.where(id: [1,2,3]).pluck(:name)
```

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question, I just wanted to know how and where to define methods for Active Record Array instances. I change the code a bit to prevent misunderstanding.

Comment: My answer still remains pretty much unchanged ... I would just write this as `Service.where(id: [1,2,3]).map(&:length)`. You *could* also simply define this as `def self.sample_method ....`, but you have not provided a sensible use case for this in either your original nor updated question.